# What are the required options in order to enable djangodblog for error logging in a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I would like to ask a question about djangodblog used for logging real time Django exception into the application database. I use the following tools

**Database:** 5.5.28 MySQL Community Server

**OS**: Fedora Core 17 (X86_64)

**Django** 1.4.2

**Python** 2.7.3

According to what I read in Jim McGaw's book : "Beginning Django E-Commerce" I defined my 
settings.py including the following items:

```
DEBUG = False
.
.
.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'djangodblog.DBLogMiddleware',
    djangodblog.middleware.DBLogMiddleware',
)
.
.
.
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangodblog',
)
```

Once I run

```
python -tt manage.py syncdb
```

All tables were created successfully (I checked by connecting to the database). However, **it seems that djangodblog is not active as there is no row inserted whenever there is an exception**. For example, let's say, you specify a template that does not yet exist or the directory path to the template is not correct. In this case, Django raises exceptions such as TemplateDoesNotExist (which you can see in the browser as a printed error StackTrace if the DEBUG is set to True within project settings.py).

Consequently, I would like to ask is there any further parameter to define/enable? in order to force Django to update error logs in MySQL as they happen in real time?

Regards,